# How to turn off auto-insert when selecting text with gVim?

Tags: vim, editor

Hello I'm a bit new still to gVim and have a vi and ViEmu(Visual Studio) background. One thing that constantly bugs me if that when I select text with the mouse it will enter `SELECT` mode. However, I can't do anything from there because whenever I press any key it will replace what I have selected with the key and automatically switch to `INSERT` mode. How do I keep this from happening and keep it in SELECT mode or at least COMMAND mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
:behave xterm
```

and put that to your vimrc.

**EDIT** : better follow Luc Hermitte's answer.

Comment: This is the answer I'm looking for. The difference being `SELECT` and `VISUAL` (I was wondering why gVim had a select mode and where that came from)

Comment: It comes from windows compatibility IMO, but over the years it has been hijacked to implement placeholders.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you ware using gvim on windows, and that you haven't deleted mswin.vim. This file is the root of many evils. My advice: get rid of it and learn vim's way of copy/pasting.

EDIT: you may also need the `behave xterm` as Benoit suggested. I don't remember if it is really required (all I can say is that my `_vimrc` has it)

Comment: I'm learning vim's way of copy/paste but I still select things with the mouse sometimes. Going to insert mode is very annoying when I do it and expect to be able to run a command

Comment: The vim way is not incompatible with the mouse. I'm using both. But not mswin.vim.

Comment: You can just take references to mswin out of your _vimrc, too.  :)  The microregion selections that I frequently get when focusing the gVim window annoyed me enough to add `vnoremap <LeftRelease>  <C-\><C-n>` to my _vimrc.  If I really wanted the selection (which is rare) I type `gv`.

Answer (score 2):

But the most direct answer is to set `selectmode` to the desired value.

```
:set selectmode&
```

The `selectmode` is set by the `behave` command (so yes, removing `behave mswin` or `source mswin.vim` and the likes does help).

Look at `:he behave` to see which values are used for xterm/mswin modes

---

Documentation `:he selectmode`

> #### `'selectmode' 'slm'   string  (default "")`
>
> ```
>       global
>       {not in Vi}
>   This is a comma separated list of words, which specifies when to start
> Select mode instead of Visual mode, when a selection is started.
> Possible values:
>    mouse    when using the mouse
>    key      when using shifted special keys
>    cmd      when using "v", "V" or CTRL-V
> See |Select-mode|. 
> The 'selectmode' option is set by the |:behave| command.
> ```

Comment: This is what I like the most.  It allows me to select holding shift and arrow keys still and also perform operations like SHIFT + . to get indentation.  Thank you!